# CPU usage going too high using Kurento media server

Tags: webrtc, communication, cpu-usage, audio-streaming, kurento

I'm using kurento media server as MCU, while using kurento I connect each receiver's WebRtcEndPoint to sender's WebRtcEndPoint.

I had installed kurento on AWS m3-medium machine and I had connected 5 users in which only 2 of them are streaming their audio. In this case my CPU usage goes to 100% and audio streaming get stopped but still connections active.

What should I do -

- Should I go for large machine. If yes what should be the configuration that sustains atleast 10 users that everyone can communicate each other simultaneously.
- Is their any other optimized way to stream audio between 10 users or more than that (I had tried composite element but the problem is same)

Comment: 5 users is only 25 WebRTC legs. It shouldn't go to 100% unless you are doing some media processing. Also, video quality may affect: the higher the quality, the higher the load. Did you check the load with each new user?

Comment: Just a silly thought, there are programs that just fully hog a single core of your CPU no matter if they actually use it, could that be the case with kurento?

Comment: what I have observed is that KMS starts to hog RAM and swap memory after 2-3 days

Comment: Did you get any solution?